# SQL query not working - Mismatch using Where condition

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I'm trying to connect one database to excel.

When the table its linked without any conditions with works perfectly.
When I'm trying to put a WHERE condition I got the type mismatch error.

```
Where Data.`InfoCreation Date`>= ?
```

On access the field is using date/time for Data type and it looks like:

```
InfoCreation Date
18/12/2018 05:49:00
```

And I am trying to match in excel with a date format type like: `18/12/2018`

What I want to have is to select all the dates before one choosed day.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Please post more of your code. Is this inside an Excel sub or Access query? It appears you are attempting to parameterize the value in `WHERE` possibly using ADO?

Comment: SELECT Data.`Ticket Mask ID`, Data.Department, Data.`InfoCreation Date`, Data.`InfoResolved Date`, Data.`InfoResolved Date`, Data.`Owner`, Data.`Subject`, Data.`Country`, Data.`Status`
FROM `O:\05 - Reports\Daily Dashboards\ALL LOBS\ALL_DB.accdb`.Data
Where Data.`InfoCreation Date`>=?

Yes, I'm using an ADO connection

Comment: Please edit your post with query and not in comments which as you can see is affected by back ticks.

Comment: Please also show your ADO code block as this really depends how you are parameterizing the date value.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert your string to a date. For that you can use [the msaccess `FORMAT()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

```
Data.`InfoCreation Date`>= Format(?, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Hi, First of all thank you for your help.~
When I'm trying your suggestion I get the error: expected 2 parameters